# Using String.Format To Dynamically Provide The Max Amount of Padding Needed

Tags: c#, string.format

Hello I am trying to make my Console Application assignment more aesthically pleasing and by doing this I have decided to implement String.Format into my loops. We haven't been taught it but it is pretty easy to pick up. The main problem here is how do I parse a int into the String.Format so that it provides the max space needed.

This is the loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
{
    int maxNumericalSize = 2;
    int fileNumberSystem = index + 1;
    string result = string.Format("{0,maxNumericalSize}: {1,20} - {2,10} - {3}", fileNumberSystem, files[index].Name, files[index].Length, files[index].LastWriteTime );
    /* Console.WriteLine(fileNumberSystem + ". " + files[index].Name + " - " + files[index].Length + " - " + files[index].LastWriteTime); */
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

As you can see MaxNumericalSize obviously throws an area as it is within speech marks so I am currently wondering how I could parse that into String.Format like that without the error.

Comment: You can convert `int` to `string` and pad that, if this is a question. It would much better if you show current output and expected one to understand what you want (sorry, but I fail to).

Comment: string result = string.Format("{0,"+maxNumericalSize+"}: {1,20} - {2,10} - {3}", fileNumberSystem, files[index].Name, files[index].Length, files[index].LastWriteTime ); should work

Answer (score 1):

Try using `string.PadLeft`/`string.PadRight` to add additional spaces as follows

```
string.Format("{0}: {1,20} ..", fileNumberSystem.ToString().PadRight(maxNumericalSize), ...);
```

For `PadRight` it works like this

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by
>   padding them with spaces on the right, for a specified total length.

There's even an overload which let's you choose a character to fill in the space. You can find more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx).